# Similarity metric for set of vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors

Consider two sets of vectors, S={[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[3,2,3]} and P={[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[3,2,3]}. I am looking for a similarity metric that would return 1 on the above.
And for instance for S={[0.9,0,0],[1,0.1,0],[3,2.1,3.3]} and P={[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[3,2,3]} a high similarity, so invariant to the index of the vectors.
I am aware of the cosine similarity (for vector comparison) and the Jaccard index (for sets comparison), but this would be some sort of combination of the two? Is there anything out there to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the average cosine similarity of all pair of vectors; and do this for all possible permutations. Take a maximum over it.

That is, given two lists of vectors $a = [a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n]$ and $b = [b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n]$, the similarity metric is as follows:

Let $\Pi_n$ be the set of all permutations of $[1, 2, \ldots n]$. An example $\pi \in \Pi_3$ is $[2, 1, 3]$.

$\text{sim}[a, b] =  \max \limits_{\pi \in \Pi_n} \dfrac{ \displaystyle \sum \limits_{i=1}^n S_C(a_i, b_{\pi(i)})}{n}  $, where $S_C$ is the cosine similarity.

This metric is symmetric, i.e. $\text{sim}[a, b] = \text{sim}[b, a]$. Also, $\text{sim}[a, a] = 1$; 
also for any $\pi \in \Pi_n$, we have $\text{sim}[a, \pi(a)] = 1$

Note that $\left| \Pi_n \right| = n!$ so this is a really expensive operation.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed a solution to the problem. The end goal is to use it as a loss metric for comparing two NN on their last convolution layer. So hopefully the steps needed will not slow the training too much.

Comment: @HectorArroyoGzlez                 As this formula contains $\max$, this function may not be differentiable; hence would be a bad candidate for a loss function I think!

Comment: That is true as well. I did like the idea of using permutations between the vectors of the sets, so may try to work with that and find something that is applicable (and post it here if I do :))